# Formik - Type 'Input' is missing the following properties from type 'HTMLInputElement': accept, align, alt, autocomplete, and 329 more

Tags: reactjs, formik

I have following Formik component:

```js
import { Input } from 'antd';
import { useField, FieldHookConfig } from 'formik';

const Text = ({ ...props }: FieldHookConfig<string>) => {
  const [field] = useField(props);
  return <Input {...field} {...props} />;
};
export default FormTextField;
```

I am getting error on Input component:

```
TS2322: Type '{ className: string | undefined; ref?: LegacyRef<HTMLInputElement> | undefined; key?: Key | null | undefined; accept?: string | undefined; ... 288 more ...; innerRef?: ((instance: any) => void) | undefined; } | { ...; } | { ...; }' is not assignable to type 'IntrinsicAttributes & IntrinsicClassAttributes<Input> & Pick<Readonly<InputProps>, "color" | ... 290 more ... | "bordered"> & InexactPartial<...> & InexactPartial<...>'.
  Type '{ className: string | undefined; ref?: LegacyRef<HTMLInputElement> | undefined; key?: Key | null | undefined; accept?: string | undefined; alt?: string | undefined; ... 287 more ...; innerRef?: ((instance: any) => void) 
| undefined; }' is not assignable to type 'IntrinsicClassAttributes<Input>'.
    Types of property 'ref' are incompatible.
      Type 'LegacyRef<HTMLInputElement> | undefined' is not assignable to type 'LegacyRef<Input> | undefined'.
        Type '(instance: HTMLInputElement | null) => void' is not assignable to type 'LegacyRef<Input> | undefined'.
          Type '(instance: HTMLInputElement | null) => void' is not assignable to type '(instance: Input | null) => void'.
            Types of parameters 'instance' and 'instance' are incompatible.
              Type 'Input | null' is not assignable to type 'HTMLInputElement | null'.
                Type 'Input' is missing the following properties from type 'HTMLInputElement': accept, align, alt, autocomplete, and 329 more.
```